# 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y' in unsupervised classification on R

Tags: r, raster

I'm trying to plot the output of a kmeans analysis on a raster stack on r and I got returned the error in the title. This is my output raster:

```
    unsuperClass results

    *************** Map ******************
    $map
    class      : RasterLayer 
    dimensions : 48219, 90691, 4373029329  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
    resolution : 10, 10  (x, y)
    extent     : 3909190, 4816100, 2404810, 2887000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
    crs        : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
    source     : r_tmp_2021-10-19_154600_2028_56752.grd 
    names      : layer 
    values     : 1, 4  (min, max)
```

As you can see, to do the analysis I used the "unsuperClass" function in RStoolbox.
And the code that returns the error:

```
    plot(unCrasterresult)
    Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
      'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

I know I need to call something like

```
    plot(unCrasterresult$x, unCrasterresult$y)
```

and set limits but I don't know exactly how to structure the code.

Edit: I've also tried this code but to no avail

```
    plot(unCrasterresult, xlim=c(3909190, 4816100), ylim=c(2404810, 2887000))
```

Comment: Instead of showing the print-output, you should show the result of class and  names when applied to that object.

Comment: You mean this? ```class(unCrasterresult)
[1] "unsuperClass" "RStoolbox"``` and ```names(unCrasterresult)
[1] "call"  "model" "map"```

Comment: Right. So the is no "x" or "y" top level element in the `unCrasterresult` object. If you use `str` on `unCrasterresult` you might be able to find a lower level (perhaps the `map` element?) that has those elements. Sometimes packages will define plotting methods for new classes, but it doesn't appear that you any packages loaded which contain plotting functions for either of the two classes that `unCrasterresult` inherits. You should realize that you are using a package that is either so new or so obscure that most people will not recognize the source of objects created by just print output.

Answer (score 0):

If one searches the web for "unsuperClass RStoolbox" the first hit is:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RStoolbox/versions/0.2.6/topics/unsuperClass

So we can deduce that you have installed and loaded the `RStoolbox` package. Looking at the documentation for the function being used we see an example:

```
library(raster)
input <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))

## Plot 
olpar <- par(no.readonly = TRUE) # back-up par
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plotRGB(input)

## Run classification
set.seed(25)
unC <- unsuperClass(input, nSamples = 100, nClasses = 5, nStarts = 5)
unC

## Plots
colors <- rainbow(5)
plot(unC$map, col = colors, legend = FALSE, axes = FALSE, box = FALSE)
legend(1,1, legend = paste0("C",1:5), fill = colors,
       title = "Classes", horiz = TRUE,  bty = "n")

par(olpar) # reset par
```

So the map element of such an object is an S4 classed object with a class of "RasterLayer":

```
str(unC$map)
Formal class 'RasterLayer' [package "raster"] with 12 slots
  ..@ file    :Formal class '.RasterFile' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
  .. .. ..@ name        : chr ""
  .. .. ..@ datanotation: chr "FLT4S"
  .. .. ..@ byteorder   : chr "little"
  .. .. ..@ nodatavalue : num -Inf
  #--- abbreviated the console output, note that this is an S4 object
```

This shows you might have success with:

```
plot(unCrasterresult$map)
```

There must be a base plot method defined for an S4 object of class "RasterLayer" in either the `RStoolbox` or `raster` package. My comment regarding the character of the package being new or obscure was based on my not finding any prior SO mention of that class, but the package has been around since 2015 and is being actively maintained. If you had posted on the SE site for GIS questions you might have gotten an immediate answer from a current user who knew  that function and package. See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=unsuperClass . There is also a R-SIG spatial mailing list: `r-sig-geo`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the raster package to be able to plot a `RasterLayer`. So something like this:

```
library(raster)
plot(unsuperClasresult$map)
```